# Cannot access virtual directory on another network server : Access denied

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory

I have a new ASP.NET web page that I am trying to secure (for the very first time) the application using a security group defined in Active Directory that contains the names of authorised AD users.

I have a Virtual directory defined up for the application (A directory on another server). The virtual directory is shared and the security group (of which the individual users a members of) have access to Read and Write to the directory on the relevant server.

This all takes place on the same domain.

The application is running in a separate Application pool

The following is in the WEB.CONFIG

```
<authentication mode="Windows" >
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

The following is a piece of test code behind a button

```
string theSSID = "";
if (Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
  theSSID = Request.LogonUserIdentity.User.ToString();
  Label1.Text = "<br />Valid User : " + Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToString() + " SSID = " + theSSID + "<br />";

  try
    {
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "A. Writing log file";
    string strFilePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"\Banking_UpLoad_Files\") + "CS_Log.txt";
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "B. Path For Log file " + strFilePath;
    StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(strFilePath);
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "C. File " + strFilePath + "Written To Network Directory";
    }
  catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + ex.Message;
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "2 .Access log from " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "2 .User: " + Request.LogonUserIdentity.User;
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "2 .Name: " + Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "2 .AuthenticationType: " + Request.LogonUserIdentity.AuthenticationType;
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "2 .ImpersonationLevel: " + Request.LogonUserIdentity.ImpersonationLevel;
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "2 .IsAnonymous: " + Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAnonymous;
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "2 .IsGuest: " + Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsGuest;
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "2 .IsSystem: " + Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsSystem;
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "2 .Owner: " + Request.LogonUserIdentity.Owner;
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />" + "2 .Token: " + Request.LogonUserIdentity.Token + "<br />";
    }
  }

  Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "<br />4. Complete <br />";
```

The code above when run on the .Net Server produces the following output

If Application pool is set to Network Service then output is

Valid User : RPS-DUNDEE\wilson SSID = ************************

A. Writing log file
B. Path For Log file \RPS-Nas-2\Finance\Banking Upload Files\CS_Log.txt

Access to the path '\RPS-Nas-2\Finance\Banking Upload Files\CS_Log.txt' is denied.

2 .Access log from 25/02/2015 12:47:31
2 .User: ********************************
2 .Name: RPS-DUNDEE\wilson
2 .AuthenticationType: Negotiate
2 .ImpersonationLevel: Impersonation
2 .IsAnonymous: False
2 .IsGuest: False
2 .IsSystem: False
2 .Owner: S-1-5-32-544
2 .Token: 1680

4. Complete

If Application pool is set to Local Service then the error is

Access to the path '\RPS-Nas-2\Finance\Banking Upload Files\CS_Log.txt' is denied.

If Application pool is set to Configurable (User Name = IWAM_DUN-SERVER3) then  then the error is

Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Can anyone assist please as this is driving me off the rails.

Regards and thanks in advance for any assistance offered

Iain

Answer (score 0):

Is "IWAM_DUN-SERVER3" a AD users?

If it isn't, create it in AD!

Then, try to define your app pool identity like this : IWAM_DUN-SERVER3@domain.com